# Problems while Handling Button Event in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

How to Handle a Button Click Event in Python? I am New to python and trying to  develop Zip Extractor tool.i've handled the Btn1 and Btn2 Properly but the  3'rd one is giving me errors.("name res1 is not defined") Here is the code 
i've Wrote as follows: Plz Help Me as i am a noobie :| Thanks In Adv :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os, zipfile

extension = ".zip"
PASSWORD = "virus007"

global res1
global res2

window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome Zip_Extractor_Utility")

window.geometry('640x260')

lbl1 = Label(window, text="Select Source Location:" ,font=("Arial Bold", 12))

lbl2 = Label(window, text="Select Destination Location:" ,font=("Arial Bold", 12))

lbl1.grid(column=0, row=7)

lbl2.grid(column=50, row=7)

def clicked1():
 res1 = askdirectory()
 print(res1)
 return res1

btn1 = Button(window, text="Browse" , command=clicked1)

btn1.grid(column=1, row=7)

def clicked2():
 res2 = askdirectory()
 print(res2)
 return res2

btn2 = Button(window, text="Browse" , command=clicked2)

btn2.grid(column=51, row=7)

##lbl3 = Label(window, text="Extract:" ,font=("Arial ", 12))
##lbl3.grid(column=70, row=7)

def clicked3():
    os.chdir(res1) # change directory from working dir to dir with files
    for item in os.listdir(res1): # loop through items in dir
            if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
                file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
                zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) # create zipfile object
                zip_ref.setpassword(PASSWORD)
                zip_ref.extractall(res2) # extract file to dir
                zip_ref.close() # close file
                #os.remove(file_name) # delete zipped file
    print('done')



btn3 = Button(window, text="Extract" , command=clicked3) 
btn3.grid(column=71, row=7)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, in the function 'clicked3()' you want to navigate to directory "res1" which is not defined. Hence the error...

Comment: Solved the issue by declaring res1 and res2 global as follows:                         
 def clicked1(): global res1
 res1 = askdirectory()
 print (res1)
 return res1           and Similarly for res 2 also. Btw Thanks for the Support :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just check if `res1` and `res2` is defined in `clicked3` function. Maybe with `'res1' in vars() and 'res2' in vars()`. If it's not defined, warn users that they need to specify source and destination folder first.